# Return HTML string from the completion handler of the evaluateJavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, swift, webkit, completionhandler

I know that I'm not the first one to ask this but I can't solve the problem. I'm trying to take a piece of string from HTML using `evaluateJavaScript` in Xcode with Swift 3 and the piece of text is called `value` inside the completion handler, so I did like this:

```
var userName = String()

   func takeData() {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelectorAll('.name')[0].innerHTML") { (value, error) in

            if let valueName = value as? String {
                self.userName = valueName
            }
            print(value)
            print(error)
        }

    }

print(" The name is : \(self.userName)")
```

The problem is that the console just prints: The name is ()

Comment: is this called after the webview has finish loading?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are printing the value before your asynchronous function could finish execution. You have several solutions to solve this issue. You can either implement `takeData` to have a completionHandler as one of its input parameters, use `GCD` to make your statements execute in the expected order or use a 3rd party library, such as [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) to handle the async requests for you, so they will behave like normal functions with a return value.

I will give you an example with the completion handler:

```
func takeData(completionHandler: @escaping (_ userName: String?) -> Void){
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.querySelectorAll('.name')[0].innerHTML") { (value, error) in
        if let valueName = value as? String {
            completionHandler(valueName)
        }
        print(value)
        print(error)
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
}
```

You use the value from the completionHandler like this:

```
takeData(completionHandler: { userName in
    print(userName)
})
```