# Ambigous reference to initializer 'init(_:)' when trying to parse Any? object to String in Swift

Tags: swift, html-parsing, wkwebview

I'm trying to parse an `Any?` object to String which contains an HTML Document that comes from a `WKWebView` after JS Execution.

If I try to print the `Html: Any?` object everything shows on console, but when I try to store it in a String var to do another stuff with it, appears the error

> Ambigous reference to initializer 'init(_:)'

**Here is my code:**

```
func getHTML() {
    miWEBVIEW.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()", completionHandler: { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
         print(html) // -> This works showing HTML on Console, but need in String to manipulate
         return html            
    })
}
```

Here is where I call the function in a button event:

```
let document: Any? = getHTML()
var documentString = String(document) // -> error appears in this line
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689874/return-html-string-from-the-completion-handler-of-the-evaluatejavascript-functio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your getTML method returns Void. You can't initialize a String object with it. Besides that WKWebView `evaluateJavaScript` is an asynchronous method. You need to add a completion handler to your getHTML method:

```
func getHTML(completion: @escaping (_ html: Any?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()",
                               completionHandler: completion)
}
```

---

Then you need call your getHTML method like this:

```
getHTML { html, error in
    guard let html = html as? String, error == nil else { return }
    self.doWhatever(with: html)
}
```

---

```
func doWhatever(with html: String) {
    print(html)
    // put your code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this actually worked to the purpose i need!